# PHP Getting apart of Name in to <a href="

Tags: php

So I have this code: More explanation below

```
<?php
include_once 'imdb.class.php'; 

$oIMDB = new IMDB('Green Lantern'); 

if ($oIMDB->isReady) 
{ 
    echo '<li class="withimage"><span class="name">' . $oIMDB->getTitle()
         . '</span><span class="comment">' . $oIMDB->getYear() 
         . '</span><span class="arrow"></span></a></li>'; 
} else {
    echo '<p>Movie not found!</p>'; 
}
?>
```

I want to get the "Green Lantern" word inside of a `<a href="">` tag. I tried to use something with `'.$oIMDB->get().'`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work" How? Does it throw an error, or does it produce an undesired result?

Answer (score 1):

Cool reading code:

```
<?php

include('imdb.class.php'); 

$oIMDB = new IMDB('Green Lantern'); 

if ($oIMDB->isReady) 
{ 
    echo "<li class='withimage'>
            <span class='name'>$oIMDB->getTitle()</span>
            <span class='comment'>$oIMDB->getYear()</span>
            <span class='arrow'></span></a></li>"; 
} else {
    echo '<p>Movie not found!</p>'; 
} 

?>
```

Wheres your 'href' tag?
Never seen IMDB api/class, but I think you should echo it, like:

```
<span class='name'><?=$oIMDB->getTitle()?></span>
```